# How to split time data in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like below:

```
d={
    'Date' :['2016-10-30','2016-10-30','2016-11-01','2016-10-30'],
    'Time':['09:58:11', '10:05:34', '10:07:57', '11:15:32'],
    'Transaction':[2,3,1,1]
}

df=pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Date','Time','Transaction'])
```

[image]

I need to create a new variable as Time_Group. For (6,11] is 'Morning' ,for (11,17] is 'Afternoon' and for (17,20] is 'Evening' for data of Time_group. How to sub create this variable by using Time column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `pd.cut` with `pd.Timedelta`:

```
u = df.assign(Time=pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']))
bins = [6,11,17,20]
labels = ['Morning','Afternoon','Evening']
u = u.assign(Time_Group=pd.cut(u['Time'],[pd.Timedelta(hours=i) for i in bins],
                               labels=labels))
```

---

```
print(u)
         Date     Time  Transaction Time_Group
0  2016-10-30 09:58:11            2    Morning
1  2016-10-30 10:05:34            3    Morning
2  2016-11-01 10:07:57            1    Morning
3  2016-10-30 11:15:32            1  Afternoon
```

Comment: Hello, here 4th raw should be Morning but, it looks Afternoon. How to fix this?

Comment: @user14815110 in your question you have written that 11-17 should be afternoon. Hence the 4th row is afternoon since it is 15 min past 11.to change the timing you can simply change the bins list from 11 to 12 for example to start the afternoon from

Answer (score 1):

You can use this -

```
d={
    'Date' :['2016-10-30','2016-10-30','2016-11-01','2016-10-30'],
    'Time':['09:58:11', '10:05:34', '10:07:57', '11:15:32'],
    'Transaction':[2,3,1,1]
}

df=pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Date','Time','Transaction'])


def time_group(inp):
    inp = datetime.datetime.strptime(inp[0], "%H:%M:%S")
    a = datetime.datetime.strptime("06:00:00", "%H:%M:%S")
    b = datetime.datetime.strptime("11:00:00", "%H:%M:%S")
    c = datetime.datetime.strptime("17:00:00", "%H:%M:%S")
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime("20:00:00", "%H:%M:%S")
    
    if a < inp <= b:
       return 'Morning'
    elif b < inp < c:
       return 'Afternoon'
    elif c < inp < d:
       return 'Night'

>>> df[['Time']].apply(time_group,axis=1)
0      Morning
1      Morning
2      Morning
3    Afternoon
dtype: object
```